# TestNG Parameterisation: NullPointerException when passing browser type to Base class

Tags: java, selenium, testng, parameter-passing

I have a Base class with a method to open my URL that is called as @BeforeMethod in my test cases. The method takes a string argument for browser type which determines which browser is called. I am attempting to set a parameter in my xml launch file that can be inputted in my @BeforeMethod as argument for the openURL method.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="FullRegressionSuite" parallel="false">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="reporting.CustomReporter"></listener>
</listeners>
  <test name="Test">
    <parameter name ="browserType" value="Chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="reporting.reporterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Here are my tests:

```
@Listeners(CustomListener.class)
public class reporterTest extends Base {

      @Test
      public void testOne() {
          Assert.assertTrue(true);
      }

      @Test
      public void testTwo() {
          Assert.assertTrue(false);
      }

      @Parameters({ "browserType" })
      @BeforeMethod
      public void setUp(String browserType) throws InterruptedException {
          System.out.println(browserType);
          openURL(browserType);
      }

      @AfterMethod 
      public void tearDown() {
          driver.quit(); 
      }
}
```

Here is my base class:

```
public class Base {

public static WebDriver driver = null;

//CALL WEB BROWSER AND OPEN WEBSITE
public static void openURL(String browser) throws InterruptedException {

        //launches browser based on argument given
    try{
        if (browser == "Chrome") {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/rossdonohoe/Desktop/SeleniumJava/Drivers/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if (browser == "Firefox") {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/rossdonohoe/Desktop/SeleniumJava/Drivers/geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: browser request not recognized");
        }

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }
    catch(Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My @BeforeMethod is definitely receiving the parameter, as I'm printing its value to check and I'm getting "Chrome" in the console. However, openURL is failing at the 'delete all cookies' line with a null pointer exception (and my line "Error: browser request not recognized' is being printed in console), indicating that the string is not reaching openURL as an argument. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `browser` is a String variable , you need to use `equals` or `contains` or `equalsIgnoreCase` to check if the `browser` that you are fetching is "Chrome" or "Firefox".

So you need to use: `if(browser.equals("Chrome"))` and `if(browser.equals("Firefox"))` as the conditions instead of the conditions that you have used.